# Is there a way to show tool tips for QRubberBand?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qrubberband

I am trying to set a tool tip for QRubberBand. This is how the constructor of the parent looks. Please note the parent is not a window, but rather a widget of a window.

```cpp
    roiRB = new QRubberBand( QRubberBand::Rectangle,this);
    roiRB->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(1,1), QPoint(100,100)));

    roiRB->setAttribute(Qt::WA_AlwaysShowToolTips); //I tried this line as mentioned in the Documentation to all parent classes of the QRubberBand.
    roiRB->setToolTip("Hello");
    roiRB->setToolTipDuration(1000);
```

However the tooltip is not popping, I tried different values for toolTipDuration as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On digging the source code of QRubberBand, I found out that in the [constructor](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qrubberband.cpp.html) of QRubberBand, the attribute  `(Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents);` is set to true. Manually setting this back to false fixed the issue.

From what I see, tooltips work on MouseEvent calls of the widget, if the this attribute is set to true, the widget ignores MouseEvents and thereby nullifying the setToolTip("abcd").

Therefore,

```cpp
roiRB = new QRubberBand( QRubberBand::Rectangle,this);
roiRB->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents,0);
```

is all you need to do. Do let me know if I have missed something.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#toolTip-prop), you can read:

> Note that by default tooltips are only shown for widgets that are children of the active window. You can change this behavior by setting the attribute `Qt::WA_AlwaysShowToolTips` **on the window, not on the widget with the tooltip**.

<sup>*emphasis mine*</sup>

You have set the attribute `Qt::WA_AlwaysShowToolTips` on the widget with the tooltip and not on the window itself which is exactly the opposite of what is mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: I did on the window as well. It didnt work out either, so I tried doing it in the tool tip and any other class between the widget and the window.

Comment: @madhavpcm In this case, you need to provide a minimal, complete and reproducible example of your issue so that we can see what's wrong. The issue may not come from somewhere you think it is, hence the need of a complete example reproducing the bug.